# Print an array(object?) without comma seperator

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, output

I am currently writing a large amount of code, but I will keep it simple.  I have a javascript array (possibly an object, still unsure exactly of the conventional naming), here is the initialization code:

```
var myArray = ["assignS" , ";" , "S"]
```

This is what I get as a console.log() from firebug on the element.  There is too much code to post as it is assigned multiple values through many for loops.  So this array (or object) is printed later as follows:

```
document.write("S -> " + myArray);
```

output:

```
 S -> assignS,;,S
```

I do not want these commas in the result, it poses problems as some elements in the array may be commas themselves.  I have ruled out the .join() method because of this, and am unsure how to proceed.

Comment: Why have you ruled out the `join` method? That seems like the logical solution.

Comment: Using `document.write` can be a very bad practice, and generally array is not expected to treat as a string. Anyway, what is your expected result? Because `["assignS",";","S"].join("")` returns `"assignS;S"`.

Comment: seems like `;` is your preferred *glue*, so: `["assignS", "S"].join(';')` would work as well. Also before ruling something out, read the docs carefully.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You ruled out the join method why, exactly?  It takes a parameter, the separator, which you can then use to specify *no* separator:

```
myArray.join("");
```

I recommend reading up on the [documentation for `.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
Also, I wouldn't recommend you use document.write, it has very few good applications.

Answer (score 3):

The `.join` method on an array will by default concatenate all items with a comma, but it takes one argument to override this to be any other string to use as the glue - including an empty string.

```
myArray.join(''); // is "assignS;S"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var a=[1,2,3,4]
var result="";
for(i= a.length-1; i>=0;i--){
    result=a[i]+result;
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=result;
```

Comment: This answer could do with more explanation - the indentation is also not quite right.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
document.write("S -> " + myArray.join(" "));
```